# Unable to tear down cgroup access when try to create a snapshot of a KVM virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, snapshot, cgroup

I want to create a snapshot of a VM on KVM using command:

virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vms1 --name vms1.snapshot --diskspec sda,file=/data/snapshots/vms1_disk.0.snap.qcow2 --disk-only --atomic

but I receive "Permission denied" error.
In syslog I see the following messages:

Sep  7 11:58:44 kvm1 libvirtd[1036]: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'blockdev-add': Could not open '/data/snapshots/vms1_disk.0.snap.qcow2': Permission denied

Sep  7 11:58:44 kvm1 libvirtd[1036]: Path '/data/snapshots/vms1_disk.0.snap.qcow2' is not accessible: No such file or directory

Sep  7 11:58:44 kvm1 libvirtd[1036]: Unable to tear down cgroup access on /data/snapshots/vms1_disk.0.snap.qcow2

I have libvirt0:amd64 version 7.0.0-3
Thanks

Comment: Hiho, I just tried `virsh snapshot-create-as --domain ubuntu22.04-desktop --name vda.snapshot1 --diskspec 'vda,file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu22.04-desktop-s1.qcow2' --disk-only --atomic` and then the same again after the domain was running (on 8.0.0-1ubuntu7.4 though). So while I couldn't reproduce to debug, this smells like a apparmor violation - could you run `journalctl -f` while doing this and report if there are any apparmor denials? Well OTH you already quotes syslog, I assume you would have mentioned a denial there, hmmm ...

Comment: It reminded me of something, ... found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1845506 where I fixed what seems to be the same issue. But that was fixed since v5.10 (wow how long ago) and you are on 7.0 already. So what could it be ...? I think we need to find a way to reproduce this, could you try the same on a clean recent Ubuntu like Jammy (22.04) and report the steps until it occurs step by step in a bug please?